# a question about an equivalent statement of almost surely convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I have seen it from a book that almost surely convergence is equivalent to the following statement:
for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n>0$, such that $P({|X_{j}-X|\geq\epsilon})=0$, for all $j\geq n.$ I doubt if it is right.

Comment: Let $X_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the random variable that is $1$ on $[0,1/n]$ and $0$ elsewhere.  $\{X_i\}$ converges a.s. to $0$, but your condition does not hold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Changed:**

*[Almost sure convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence)* is $\Pr\!\left( \lim_{n\to\infty}\! X_n = X \right) = 1$.

[These notes](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture38.pdf) give the example

> Let the sample space $S$ be the closed interval $[0, 1]$ with the
>   uniform probability distribution. Define random variables $X_n(s) = s + s^n$ and $X(s) = s$. For every $s \in [0, 1)$, $s_n \rightarrow 0$
>   as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $X_n(s) \rightarrow s = X(s)$. However,
>   $X_n(1) = 2$ for every $n$ so $X_n(1)$ does not converge to $1 =
> X(1)$. But since the convergence occurs on the set $[0, 1)$ and $P([0,
> 1)) = 1$, $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely.

But for this example $|X_j-X|\geq\epsilon$ when $\epsilon^{1/j} \leq s \leq 1$, and that has positive probability $1-\epsilon^{1/j}$ for all positive $j$ and all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.   So this example has almost sure convergence but does not have the convergence you describe.

Comment: nice counterexample, thank you